# Best way to configure multinode cassandra cluster deployment

Tags: deployment, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Although I have worked with cassandra at application level, I do not have deployment experience. For my grad project, I need to deploy cassandra to multiple nodes in futuregrid.org just wondering if there are any tools to deploy cassandra just by giving hostnames and few conf options.

Otherwise I have wrote a small deployment script but I am not able to figure out how to create single cassandra.yaml file that can be used to instantiate all instances of cassandra by ssh-ing to those nodes. [This page](http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/install/cluster_init) seems to hint that we might need to create separate configurations per node and then instantiate them, but I might be missing something.

Some background regarding my setup:

1. I am using resources from futuregrid.org, you can assume that each node is similar to other, so I strictly do not need separate conf.
2. I am using DSE 4 version.

Please advise. Any pointers on either of these would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through some iterations on this in the comments, in most cases you won't need to do node specific customizations of cassandra.yaml. The one I tend to set (because I have multiple interfaces in many of my machines) is listen_address, but as https://stackoverflow.com/users/56076/don-branson points out, if you leave that blank the system will sort that one out for you.

Check http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/deploy/deploySingleDC.html for more current information just in case.

Comment: Per node? That surprises me, based on what I've read of Cassandra. I'd expected that all the nodes would be configured identically. What are examples of settings that will differ between nodes?

Comment: It should always be blank in multi-node, according to the comment in the file:  "# Leaving it blank leaves it up to InetAddress.getLocalHost(). This
# will always do the Right Thing _if_ the node is properly configured
# (hostname, name resolution, etc), and the Right Thing is to use the
# address associated with the hostname (it might not be)."

Comment: Good point... I traditionally have always set this because most of my machines have multiple interfaces, and I wanted to make sure it's the right one.

Comment: Ah, okay. Still, I'd not want to do that for a large cluster. At least, not manually.

Comment: Agreed :-). I actually also filed a ticket for the docs to make clear that in a standard setup, the empty listen_address is preferred. With that said, I would say that there isn't really any need for node specific customizations (afaik).

Comment: Good point. Any idea if I can set to something like 10.0.*.* to just bind to specific interfaces. Is there any disadvantage of keeping it blank for it bind to all interfaces.?

Comment: Wildcards won't work afaik. A blank listen_address will pick the "right" interface. The use of 0.0.0.0 (for all) won't work for listen_address. What you may want to do (what others seem to have done :-) is set the rpc_address to 0.0.0.0 to allow the use of all interfaces and setting listen_address to an internal address (an internface not exposed to the outside).